# Import error with MongoDB Java async driver

Tags: java, mongodb, asynchronous

I'm using the async MongoDB Java Driver version 3.4.2, and I am building the project with Gradle (to be specific, I'm building `org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-async:3.4.0`). When I import the line:

```
import com.mongodb.Block;
```

the import works just fine, but when I try to import:

```
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
```

I get an error:

```
error: cannot find symbol
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
```

What is the issue with my import here? In the most recent API documentation, MongoDB says that `BasicDBObject` is still located within the package `com.mongodb`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/tree/master/driver) and [driver-async](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/tree/master/driver-async) are two separate independent modules.

`BasicDBObject` is part of `driver` while `Block` is part of `driver-async`.

Comment: Could I ask how you know that information? I've tried adding the package `org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-core:3.4.0` to my Gradle build, but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Dug into the different drivers some more, and I found the import I needed by importing `org.mongodb:mongodb-driver:3.4.0`.

Comment: My apologies its driver module. I have maven project and I either take a look at pom or run mvn dependency tree goal to find all  the dependencies for a jar.